# How to upload data for analysis in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to add to it a feature for uploading data. I tried conditional panels but no luck. I attach my code below. What I did was I included the simulated data before the ui part of shiny and constructed the rest of the code. Thanks

```
library(shiny)
```

dat # data
**ui**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Correlation coefficient and scatter plots'),
    sidebarPanel(
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like `fileInput`? See http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/upload-file.html